# What does this error mean: Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have a problem with my viewresult for my index page. I have searched here and on Google for the solution. So here is my code.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private ProjectsDB db = new ProjectsDB();
    //
    // GET: /User/
    EnvironmentVariableTarget 

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var model = from p in db.Projects where p.UserName == User.Identity.Name select p;
        return View(model);
    }
```

And this is my error:

> Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your action method looks OK. You probably have some error above that code.

Comment: What is the name of your controller class?  Is it "Index"?

Comment: Above that code is auto generated by mvc. @John no it's projects

Comment: What's that `EnvironmentVariableTarget`? Remove that line and you should be OK.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic Thanks wow that was easy. I don't have enough rep to up-vote You but will mark as answer. [Edit] That is if this was an answer so no go.

Comment: @Frazzle pollirrata already added this as an answer, so you should accept that. Comments cannot be accepted as answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That `EnvironmentVariableTarget` part is wrong. It shouldn't be there, that's why you get the error on the next sentence